# Port-Forwarding SVN Server

Tags: virtualbox, svn, port-forwarding

I have two networks that are completely disjoint. I have a virtual machine on network A and a host Windows 7 machine on network B. My SVN server lives in network A and I would like to be able to access it from my host Windows 7 computer. In network B, if you try to connect to the svn server, you will get a connection timeout because it is not accessible from network B.

I setup port forwarding in virtual box to forward port 80 from the svn server in network B to port 8443 on my host machine. If I telnet from my host machine, it does return data on port 8443 of my host machine.

However, if I do an svn checkout on my host machine, it fails with the following error:

```
svn co http://localhost:8443/svn/myProject
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'mySvnServer' : Could not resolve hostname 'mySvnServer' : No such host is known.
```

This makes sense since my host machine legitimately can't resolve the hostname for mySvnServer (host machine is on network A and mySvnServer is on network B). How do I turn off the resolving of the hostname or make it use the forwarded port for the svn service?

Comment: How are the networks separated?  Are they physically connected, just different subnets?  Different physical networks?  What OS are you running on the server?  What are you using as a DNS server?

Comment: use the ip address (127.0.0.1) of localhost instead of the hostname?